# OpenCV reading RGB Values. Values are not consistent for every run

Tags: c++, opencv

When running this code with the same image and mask I occasionally get values that differ previously. For example

[Normal/Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9COfV.png)

[Abnormal Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y79S7.png)

As can be seen in the two results I somehow receive negative RGB values. The Abnormal Results show up around every 5-8 runs for the exact same image with the exact same mask.

What do I need to change to prevent the occasional abnormal result?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

float get_color(Mat img,Mat &mask){
    Mat img1 = img;
    Mat hist;
    int dims = 1;
    int histSize = 255;
    float hranges[] = { 0, 255 };
    const float *ranges = {hranges};

    calcHist(&img1,1,0,mask,hist, dims, &histSize, &ranges ,true ,false);

    int sum=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<256;i++){
        sum += hist.at<float>(i,0);
    }
    Mat weights = hist/sum;
    float hist_avg=0.0;
    for(int i = 0;i<256;i++){
        hist_avg += i*weights.at<float>(i,0);
    }
    return hist_avg;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Mat aa = imread("/Users/dnguyen/Desktop/snapshot207042/pic.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    vector<Mat> bgr;
    split(aa, bgr);
    Mat b = bgr[0];
    Mat g = bgr[1];
    Mat r = bgr[2];
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<23;i++){
        stringstream ss;
        ss << i;
        string str = ss.str();
        string file_name =     "/Users/dnguyen/Desktop/okay/data/card_masks/"+str+"_mask.png";
        Mat mask = imread(file_name,0);
        Mat cc;
        threshold(mask,cc,90,255,THRESH_BINARY);

        float b_avg = get_color(b, cc);
        float g_avg = get_color(g, cc);
        float r_avg = get_color(r, cc);

        cout  << b_avg << ","<< g_avg << "," << r_avg << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You access up to an including `hist.at<float>(255,0)`, you should initialize `histSize = 256`, along with `float hranges[] = { 0, 256 };`

Comment: Your `get_color()` function; you pass `Mat img` by value and end up creating a temporary on the stack within the function's body only to pass its reference to `calcHist`. Are you able to change the signature of `get_color` to `float get_color( Mat & img, Mat & mask ) { ... }` to get rid of the temporary, and just pass in the reference into `calcHist(...)`? I do not see you using the stack variable `img1` anywhere else in the function. I only mention this for performance reasons. Less memory use and more efficient to run, prevent the copying of a `Mat` object only to pass it by reference.

Comment: The only thing I see as a concern might be this line of code: `Mat weights = hist/sum;` unless if the problem is within `calcHist()`. Your `Mat` objects are of type `float` internally as it appears from your code. Here you have `Mat::member<float> / int`. This could be truncation due to round off errors, it could be from your other function, and I doubt that it's a bug in the API you are using, although it could be.